# Constructing a matrix that satisfies a relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let **a** and **b** denote $n \times 1$ vectors, and let $\tau$ represent a threshold. Given that $\|$**a**$\| \leq \tau$, how can I construct **b** such that $\|$**a**+**b**$\| \leq \tau$ is satisfied. Is there any bound for **b**?

Comment: $\lVert b \rVert\le \tau-\lVert a\rVert$ is the first one that comes to mind. In a way, the best one of this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting $b'=-b$, your problem is transformed into the equivalent one:

Find $b'$ such that $\|a-b'\| \leq \tau$.

Let us simplify the issue by thinking in 2D (instead of hyperballs : disks, of hyperspheres, circles).

Let $C_0$ (resp. $C_a$) be the disk with center $0$ (resp. $a$) and radius $\tau$ (resp. $\|a\|$):  $b'$ should be chosen in the lens-shaped   $C_0 \cap C_a$.  Therefore, the set of points $b$ is the symmetrical set of this set.

Thus, $\|b\|\leq \tau$.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but could you please elaborate further. What if there is no intersection? How did you choose a center for $C_a$. Is this a sharp upper-bound?

Comment: There is necessarily an intersection because $a$ is within circle $C_0$ (center 0, radius $\tau$). The center for $C_a$ is $a$ (the extremity of vector $a$, if you "think" vector $a$ as having its origin in $0$ and extremity in "point a"). The best is to draw a figure...